# How to boil down $n*k + (n+1)*k + (n+2)*k + (n+3)*k + \ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

How do I express this in a singel function to be used for exampke in Excel?

$$n*k + (n+1)*k + (n+2)*k + (n+3)*k \ldots$$

$k$ is a constant and $n$ is counting from $1$ to infinity. For example: $k=5$, $n$ starts at $1$ for $4$ iterations.

$$1*5 + 2*5 + 3*5 + 4*5$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless $k = 0$, the infinite sum will not converge.  But if you want the sum of a finite number of terms, say from $n = 1$ to $n = m$, where in your example you chose $m = 4$, then the sum has a convenient closed form:
$$\sum_{n=1}^m kn = \frac{km(m+1)}{2}.$$  So with your choice $k = 5$, $m = 4$, your sum is $$1(5) + 2(5) + 3(5) + 4(5) = \frac{5(4)(4+1)}{2} = 50.$$  In Excel, if `A1` contains the value of $k$ and `A2` contains the value of $m$, then your sum could be entered in `A3` as `=A1*A2*(A2+1)/2`.

Answer (score 1):

We have, letting $m$ be the number of terms:

$$nk + (n+1)k + (n+2)k + \dots + (n+m-1)k =nmk + (1 + 2 + \dots + (m-1))k$$

Using $1 + 2 + \dots + a = \frac{a(a+1)}{2}$:

$$=\boxed{nmk + \frac{m(m-1)k}{2}}$$